# Packaging Unix utilities as part of a Cocoa App

Tags: cocoa, unix, distribution, packaging

I'm currently writing a Cocoa app that uses pdftotext from xpdf, which I personally have because of homebrew.

How can I package xpdf with my Cocoa app for distribution so it works for any end user without requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just put the binary into your bundle and distribute it with your app. IANAL, but note that xpdf and tools are GPL, so you need to make the user aware (e.g. in the about screen) that you are using xpdf, and where the user can get the source. Make sure that pdftotext does not create any settings in ~/ outside of the user's Library folder, or Apple will reject the app. But I guess you know the restrictions for OS X apps in the App Store. You could also try to use libpoppler as a framework in your app, but this will make your app GPL, if you don't mind that.

Edit: I can simply point you to the [Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010572). They explicitly deal with helper applications. However, I think your pdftext is not really a helper application, since the user never runs it himself. But still, then the [before mentioned guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010572) still apply.

Comment: Is making the user aware that you call xpdf really a requirement of the GPL?

Comment: I quote the GPL: "For example, if you distribute copies of such a program, whether gratis or for a fee, you must give the recipients all the rights that you have. You must make sure that they, too, receive or can get the source code. And you must show them these terms so they know their rights."